# Want to password protect a Wordpress page and have a PHP function validate the password

Tags: php, wordpress

This is so I can apply a regular expression to the supplied password and give a yes/no with a simple regular expression.

Before everyone jumps on me to say this is terribly insecure, I know.  It is intended to be used to to protect family photos.  My family knows the name of my cat, so I'll accept a variety of passwords, based on that, with a simple regular expression.

I've searched a bunch, but no idea how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways, 
write a dedicated page template - See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

OR

write privacy shortcode that brackets content https://codex.wordpress.org/shortcode#Escaping_Shortcodes

For all: serve up form html if no password passed, else if password and correct then serve page content.